# Where are the messages sent to the queue with a name that does not match the address name?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I created a queue with a name that does not match the address name

[image]

Then I send a message to the queue with the name QUEUE

[image]

The code completed without errors, but the message did not appear in the queue with the name QUEUE and also in DLQ, there are also no errors in the Artemis logs. Where did the messages go?

apache-artemis v. 2.11.0, default config after creat broker

Also the second question, is it possible to send a message directly to such a queue, the name of which is different from the name of the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic addressing model used by ActiveMQ Artemis - send messages to an **address**, consume them from a **queue**. How messages are routed from the address to the queue depends on the configured **routing-type**. You can read all about this in the [address model documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html).

If you send a message to an address that doesn't exist then it will be routed nowhere. In other words it will just be discarded. If you want to catch these kinds of messages in a dead-letter resource then you can set:

```xml
<address-settings>
   <address-setting match="#">
      <dead-letter-address>DLA</dead-letter-address>
      <send-to-dla-on-no-route>true</send-to-dla-on-no-route>
   </address-setting>
</address-settings>
<addresses>
   <address name="DLA">
      <anycast>
         <queue name="DLQ" />
      </anycast>
   </address>      
</addresses>
```

This is discussed in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#configuring-addresses-and-queues-via-address-settings).

If for some reason you want to send a message *directly* to a queue then you can use the fully qualified queue name (i.e. FQQN) which follows the pattern `<address>::<queue>`. So in your case you'd use:

```java
final Destination dest = session.createQueue("ADD::QUEUE");
```

This is also discussed in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#fully-qualified-queue-names).

You'd probably also benefit from reading [the documentation about how JMS concepts are mapped onto the core API](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/jms-core-mapping.html).

Comment: I have set these parameters, now yes the message comes to DLQ. But 16 more messages with incomprehensible content also come to the DLQ. What are these messages?

Comment: Without more details about the messages it's impossible for me to say what they are. It's possible they are notification messages which are emitted as part of normal broker operation. These messages are typically not routed anywhere unless there is something specifically listening on the notification address. If that's the case then you may want to adjust the `match` of your `address-setting` to *not* use `#` and instead use something more specific.